# Extract part of the line, parse it afterwards, and change it with a new text

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing

I'm building a `C++` code generator in python. I have a `C++` template file that look like this (this is just a part of the template file but the rest is almost the same):

```cpp
/* Pass 1: Process columns one by one */
for (int j = 0; j < uiTrSize; j++)
{
    /* butterfly_0 - permutation to even and od parts */
    tmp_0_0 = block[j * uiStride + 0] + block[j * uiStride + 3];
    tmp_0_3 = block[j * uiStride + 0] - block[j * uiStride + 3];
    tmp_0_1 = block[j * uiStride + 1] + block[j * uiStride + 2];
    tmp_0_2 = block[j * uiStride + 1] - block[j * uiStride + 2];

    /* lifting_step_0 */
    // this is A2; pi/4
    tmp = tmp_0_0 + (<< **tmp_0_1_lift_step_to_add_p1 ** >>);                                  // add lift by p1
    coeff[j * uiTrSize + 2] = (<< **tmp_lift_step_to_add_u1 ** >>) - tmp_0_1;                  // add lift by u1
    coeff[j * uiTrSize + 0] = tmp - (<< **coeff[j * uiTrSize + 2] _lift_step_to_add_b1 ** >>); // add lift by b1

    // 3pi/8
    tmp = tmp_0_2 + (<< **tmp_0_3_lift_step_to_add_p2 ** >>);                                  // add lift by p2
    coeff[j * uiTrSize + 3] = tmp_0_3 - (<< **tmp_lift_step_to_add_u2 ** >>);                  // add lift by u2
    coeff[j * uiTrSize + 1] = tmp + (<< **coeff[j * uiTrSize + 3] _lift_step_to_add_b2 ** >>); // add lift by b2
}
```

What I need is to find lines with the pattern `<<** VARIABLE_lift_step_to_add_COEFFICIENT **>>`, than to find which VARIABLE and which COEFFICIENT apply for that line. Note that VARIABLE and COEFFICIENT are different names in each line, and I should extract their exact names.
That will be used to generate a new code. This is the first part to find that part of the string. At the end I should get something like:

```cpp
variable = tmp_0_1
coeff = p1
```

Than, assume I have generated a new code (string) using a variable and coefficient, I have to replace that string instead the given pattern in that particular line.
For example, in the line that contains `<<** tmp_0_1_lift_step_to_add_p1 **>>`, I should put the new string lets say for now just simple `tmp_0_1 + p1` (in practice new string is more complicated).

So, wherever I have a pattern like this `<<** VARIABLE_lift_step_to_add_COEFFICIENT **>>`, I should put the new string with different variable and coefficient name. In the example that I provided, it should occur 6 times.

Any idea how to do that? I guess it has to do something with regular expressions in python using `re` module, but so far I was not able to figure out  how to solve this problem.

The code is in python.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `re.sub()` with back-references to search groups e.g. `\1`, `\2`:

```
data = '''/* Pass 1: Process columns one by one */
  for (int j = 0; j < uiTrSize; j++)
  {
    /* butterfly_0 - permutation to even and od parts */
    tmp_0_0 = block[j*uiStride + 0] + block[j*uiStride + 3];
    tmp_0_3 = block[j*uiStride + 0] - block[j*uiStride + 3];
    tmp_0_1 = block[j*uiStride + 1] + block[j*uiStride + 2];
    tmp_0_2 = block[j*uiStride + 1] - block[j*uiStride + 2];

    /* lifting_step_0 */
    // this is A2; pi/4
    tmp = tmp_0_0 + (<<** tmp_0_1_lift_step_to_add_p1 **>>); // add lift by p1
    coeff[j*uiTrSize + 2] = (<<** tmp_lift_step_to_add_u1 **>>) - tmp_0_1; // add lift by u1
    coeff[j*uiTrSize + 0] = tmp - (<<** coeff[j*uiTrSize + 2]_lift_step_to_add_b1 **>>); // add lift by b1

    // 3pi/8
    tmp = tmp_0_2 + (<<** tmp_0_3_lift_step_to_add_p2 **>>); // add lift by p2
    coeff[j*uiTrSize + 3] = tmp_0_3 - (<<** tmp_lift_step_to_add_u2 **>>); // add lift by u2
    coeff[j*uiTrSize + 1] = tmp + (<<** coeff[j*uiTrSize + 3]_lift_step_to_add_b2 **>>); // add lift by b2
 }'''

import re

s = re.sub(r'<<\*\*\s*(.*?)_lift_step_to_add_(.*?)\s*\*\*>>', r'\1+\2', data)

print(s)
```

Prints:

```
/* Pass 1: Process columns one by one */
  for (int j = 0; j < uiTrSize; j++)
  {
    /* butterfly_0 - permutation to even and od parts */
    tmp_0_0 = block[j*uiStride + 0] + block[j*uiStride + 3];
    tmp_0_3 = block[j*uiStride + 0] - block[j*uiStride + 3];
    tmp_0_1 = block[j*uiStride + 1] + block[j*uiStride + 2];
    tmp_0_2 = block[j*uiStride + 1] - block[j*uiStride + 2];

    /* lifting_step_0 */
    // this is A2; pi/4
    tmp = tmp_0_0 + (tmp_0_1+p1); // add lift by p1
    coeff[j*uiTrSize + 2] = (tmp+u1) - tmp_0_1; // add lift by u1
    coeff[j*uiTrSize + 0] = tmp - (coeff[j*uiTrSize + 2]+b1); // add lift by b1

    // 3pi/8
    tmp = tmp_0_2 + (tmp_0_3+p2); // add lift by p2
    coeff[j*uiTrSize + 3] = tmp_0_3 - (tmp+u2); // add lift by u2
    coeff[j*uiTrSize + 1] = tmp + (coeff[j*uiTrSize + 3]+b2); // add lift by b2
 }
```

Comment: Ok, it helped a bit. But what I eventually need is to change a line with a more complicated code than simple using r'\1+\2'. For that I'll need to create separate function, that based on the parameters that I got earlier will create different code. Is there any way to pass those arguments to a function, lets call it generate_code(r'\1,r'\2)?

Comment: @MilosR. You can have function/lambda instead of second parameter of re.sub and put your logic there. I'm now on mobile, but see manual pages of re.sub